# Test whether a directory was created in Swift

Tags: swift, macos

According to the documentation, `createDirectory` can throw an error if something goes wrong. However, the return value is:

> true if the directory was created, true if createIntermediates is set and the directory already exists, or false if an error occurred.

I want to test whether a directory was created or it already exists. I though something like the following would do:

```swift
do {
    let dirOK = try fileManager.createDirectory(atPath: toDirectory, withIntermediateDirectories: true)
    if dirOK {
        print("ok")
    }
    else {
        print("no")
    }
}
catch let error as NSError {
    print(error)
}
```

However, I get the error message:

> Cannot convert value of type '()' to expected condition type 'Bool'

How do I check whether a directory was actually created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble is that you didn't read the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1407884-createdirectory) well enough. But it's not your fault, really; they are also badly written! After the part about returning a Bool, which you quoted, the docs proceed to contradict themselves:

> In Swift, this method returns Void and is marked with the throws keyword to indicate that it throws an error in cases of failure.

So there's your answer: there is no Bool returned after all. Just remove your `dirOK` and don't worry. If there's a problem creating the directory, the `try` will fail (with a `throw` from the file manager) and you'll fall into the `catch` block in good order. If you reach the next line of the `do` block *after* the `try` line, it succeeded.

```
do {
    try fileManager.createDirectory(atPath: toDirectory, withIntermediateDirectories: true)
    print("ok")
}
catch let error as NSError {
    print(error)
}
```

**NOTE** In general, the pattern here is just how most Objective-C error-generating methods work; if Objective-C had "returns a Bool and sets an NSError by indirection", Swift automatically has "returns nothing and throws if there's a problem".

Comment: Ah, I just looked a little further, and there is the second part. I gather that the function is a Swift wrapper around another which does return `Bool`. Is it possible to test whether the directory already existed with this method? I know it won’t throw an error if it does.

Comment: It is possible to test whether the directory already existed with some other method, beforehand. But in general, who cares? All you need to know is that with your `true` you will create the intermediates if needed, and if not needed, no harm done. — I suppose if you _really_ wanted that Bool you could write this part of the code _in Objective-C_ and call it by means of a trampoline method, but to me that feels unnecessary.

Comment: By the way, if possible, do _not_ call the `atPath` variant of a FileManager method, ever. URLs are the way to go.

Comment: The function is not a Swift wrapper, by the way; it's just the standard built-in renamification of the Objective-C function. If you write the same function yourself in Objective-C and exposed it to Swift, you'd get the same syntax and the same behavior. See my note at the end of my answer.